# How do I add inline CSS into the Wordpress Visual Composer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I might be asking the wrong question (I'm not a coder), but I'm attempting to paste HTML and the inline stylesheet into the text-side (HTML-side) of the Wordpress Visual Composer to create an email layout, and the finished product of that is the entire stylesheet written out above the un-styled HTML layout, so I'm assuming inline stylesheets are not supported in this composer.

[image: HTML view inside Visual Composer]
[image: Visual view inside Visual Composer]
[image: Broken email]

Some back story for clarity, I'm using the plugin 'Download After Email' which only provides the standard Wordpress visual composer in order to create the email a user receives once they 'sign up'. This seemingly limits me to either jazzing up some text a little bit like I was using Microsoft Word (which isn't sufficient for a brand-focused business), or using raw standalone HTML, which isn't really sufficient for a properly formatted template.

Are there any plugins which may assist in adding CSS styling here that will work once it's displayed externally to the website, i.e. in an email browser?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the image, you have a regular editor but not Visual Composer, and this is very good because this is the only right direction! You cannot create email templates using the constructor (Visual Composer) since creating an email template requires special old school knowledge (Tables, inline styles) and clean markup. I advise you to take a ready-made template and change it to your own.

Example: https://colorlib.com/etc/email-template/3/index.html

**What you need to know**:

1. You need to use html tables
2. You need to use inline css
3. Use full src to display images (https://yoursite.wp/.../demo.jpg) the link you can get from the media post

**Not recommended:**

1. To use css styles in the header if you are interested in Gmail App support:
   https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/
2. Custom fonts
3. Visual Composer and any other constructor

---

**Addition:**

If you can use the shortcode system I recommend creating a mini plugin for you:

- **plugins/my-custom-emails** *[Root directory of new plugin]*
- **plugins/my-custom-emails/my-custom-emails.php**  *[Main php file of plugin]*
- **plugins/my-custom-emails/emails/**  *[Directory for for all your templates]*
- **plugins/my-custom-emails/emails/template1.html** *[First demo template]*

**my-custom-emails.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My emails
Description: My custom emails
Version: 0.1.0
*/

define('MYCELS_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

add_shortcode( 'myemails', 'MYCELS_SHORTCODE' );
function MYCELS_SHORTCODE($attrs) {
    if(empty($attrs['id'])) {
        return 'ID required';
    }
    $ID = $attrs['id'];
    $PATH = MYCELS_DIR . 'emails/'.$ID.'.html';
    if(file_exists($PATH)) {
        return file_get_contents($PATH);
    } else {
        return 'File with '. $ID . ' ID not exists';
    }
}
```

**template1.html**

```
<div>
    Template
</div>
```

**And using:**

```
[myemails id=template1]
```

Id = template name

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes sorry it's the regular editor (got the name wrong).

In regards to the template, it's a ready-made template including the inline CSS styling and HTML layout. The issue I'm finding is that the Wordpress editor has no idea what CSS is, and breaks it as soon as it's saved, leaving just the unstyled HTML and a wall of CSS text.

Comment: Do not use a visual editor, make the template in a separate file on your computer, test it in a browser (Since this is a simple html, this will work) after you make sure that your template works, insert the body content (Or the whole file, depends from the settings of your plugin) to the editor with the "Text" mode, do not switch to the Visual mode, try to save, it should work

Comment: Unfortunately this is the issue I'm facing. The template is from a separate file, complete with the inline CSS and the HTML structure/content, and works fine in a browser. Using only the 'text' mode it breaks as soon as it is saved. The editor recognises the HTML and leaves it unchanged, but doesn't recognise any CSS and breaks it all. The template doesn't work without the CSS, and as this is for external use (in emails) the CSS must be inline.

Comment: Can you use the shortcode system? Then it simplifies the task

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very customisable this plug-in would work,
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-html-mail/
It’s very good and would recommend!
With this you have full control over CSS and the HTML also comes with templates and has so much more control for what you need!